# Button 'popping'

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The website I'm working on has popping slider buttons, and I'm not sure why. I know it's related to the transform: translateY property, but changing settings, looking through papers -- have all turned up nothing (as far as I can tell).

How on Earth do you keep the button of jumping out of place in regards to translate animations in IE?

site (for reference) https://fishfighterproducts.com
slider at top (buttons in red)

Answer (score 0):

The styling for the button is:

```
.home-intro-slider .home-slider-btn {
    font-size: 2.5vmin;
    background: linear-gradient( #c10000, #660000);
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -.2vmin -.1vmin black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    padding: 2% 10%;
    box-shadow: 0px .2vmin #330000 !important;
    border-bottom: .5vmin solid #330000 !important;
    border-right: .25vmin solid #330000 !important;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: .5vmin;
    margin: 0px 5%;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out !important;
    -ms-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out !important;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in-out !important;
}
.home-intro-slider .home-slider-btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px .1vmin #330000 !important;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(.2vmin);
    -ms-transform: translateY(.2vmin);
    transform: translateY(.2vmin);
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out !important;
    -ms-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out !important;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
.home-intro-slider .home-slider-btn:active {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4px) !important;
    -ms-transform: translateY(4px) !important;
    transform: translateY(4px) !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out !important;
    -ms-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out !important;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in-out !important;
}
```

Just remove the :hover and :active parts.

I found it by right clicking the button to inspect and the classes were `home-slider-btn heading-left` and `home-slider-btn` seemed most likely so going through the link provided in the styles window I went to [the css file](https://fishfighterproducts.com/content/cache/wpfc-minified/ae509ff11223e9068b0f9d291c1d4f47/1487031330index.css) where I searched the class.

Comment: Well, it's that on chrome, it looks like a button being pressed. I'd rather keep it and put it in a way that's compatible with IE than just remove the functionality altogether.

Comment: @JoelHager I'm confused, you both want and don't want the button having the translateY animation.

Comment: Well, I think there's a disconnect between what I'm wanting and what I'm getting. The translate *is* what I want, but in IE, it's not just translating; It's literally 'jumping' out of position. If you view the link I provided in IE, and hover over the button, you'll see it. It's very clearly a bug; Something that's not intended. However, in Firefox and chrome, it works as I would like it to. What I'm trying to do is get the IE version to match the Chrome/FF version. Hope that clarifies. Thanks!

Comment: @JoelHager I haven't got IE so I can't test but could it be to do with missing the `!important` on `transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;`?

Comment: I've tried that to no avail. It's weird, but because it only pops when you leave the hover state. It seems like it's not calculating the translate accurately, or out of order, but to my knowledge, it's all correct. 

http://imgur.com/a/ZM2x0

Comment: @JoelHager Oh, that is very weird; no idea without being able to get my hands on it :/